# PHP Array Intersect dont include empty arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 4 arrays, which are going to be different every time I run my code. Sometimes, maybe empty. I am using `array_intersect` to get the common value from the set of arrays and if any one of the array is empty it returns me an empty array. I want `array_intersect` to ignore empty array's.

Example:

```
$array1 = array('441', '442', '443');
$array2 = array('441', '443');
$array3 = array('441', '442',);
$array4 = array();

var_dump(array_intersect($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4));

// Returns
array('');

// Required
array('441');
```

How do I make it ignore `$array4` and give an output of `441`

Comment: This is how the function works. And everything else would not make sense. You need to check if your array is empty before you call the function - and then either include it in the list of parameters, or not.

Comment: I know, but that what I exactly asked in the question. How do I make `array_intersect` ignore the empty array

Comment: Is there always only 4 arrays?

Comment: Yea always 4 but any one could be empty

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you store your arrays as an array you can do this:

```
<?php
// create array of arrays
$array[] = array('441', '442', '443');
$array[] = array('441', '443');
$array[] = array('441', '442');
$array[] = array();

// filter out empty array
$array = array_filter($array);

// pass in array (inline argument unpacking PHP > 5.6)
print_r(array_intersect(...$array));

Array
(
    [0] => 441
)
```

https://3v4l.org/MD3r2

Answer (score 2):

```
$tempArray = [];
if (count($g_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $g_arr;
if (count($c_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $c_arr;
if (count($k_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $k_arr;
if (count($m_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $m_arr;
if (count($p_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $p_arr;

$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $tempArray);
```

Comment: That's a bad practice I think !

Comment: Why `count()`? You could just check if it's `empty()`, and these variable names are not descriptive in the slightest

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on below solution:

```
$array = array(); //initialize $arrar
$array[] = array('441', '442', '443');
$array[] = array('441', '443');
$array[] = array('441', '442',);
$array[] = array();
$array = array_filter($array); //filter empty array
$res_arr = array_shift($array); // Shift an element off the beginning of array
foreach($array as $filter){
        $res_arr = array_intersect($res_arr, $filter);
}

print_r($res_arr);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => 441 )
```

See example at: https://3v4l.org/Rkt1R

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = array('441', '442', '443');
$array2 = array('441', '443');
$array3 = array('441', '442',);
$array4 = array();


function get_intersect(...$arrays){
    $instersect_arrays = array();

    foreach($arrays as $array){
        if(!empty($array)){
            array_push($instersect_arrays,$array);
        }
    }

    return call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $instersect_arrays);
}

var_dump(get_intersect($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4));

//output: array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "441" }
```